# Use twig's {% spaceless %} tag only under certain conditions

Tags: templating

Is there a way to use Twig's `{% spaceless %}` tag only under certain conditions?

For example, say you wanted the HTML to be spaceless in the live environment but wanted it uncompressed in the dev environment. I tried something like:

```
{% if isDev %}
    {% spaceless %}
{% endif %}
{# Some code... #}
{% if isDev %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endif %}
```

But this just throws a Twig error.

Comment: What is the Twig error that returns? Also out of curiosity, what would be the reason you would need to change the code on live/dev environments like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Twig (sometimes) complains if you're splitting tags which belong together into different conditionals, I ran into that issue in a similar situation.

But as already noted in the comments, I'm also curious why you want to split the `spaceless` tag. If it's about minifying HTML, the tag isn't very efficient anyways and I'd recommend to use something like Andrew Welch's [Minify plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/minify) instead.

Comment: It was about minifying the HTML but I wasn't aware of its lack of efficiency nor of the Minify plugin. Great tip! I will get on to that now, plus I've seen that it has a nice config that disables it for dev envioronments.

Answer (score 7):

You could do it by buffering your output, i.e.

```
{% set output %}
{# Your code here #}
{% endset %}

{% if isDev %}
     {{ output }}
{% else %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {{ output }}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, I wasn't aware of the `{% set %}{% endset %}` pair

Comment: Thx, I like that idea. I use the untouched HTML for local and dev server and the spaceless option for production.